# checking desktop power supply voltage range.

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have a few computers. I know some of the power supply is 110-220 and some are only 220. I need to figure out which ones are which. How do I do that? I can't seem to find it in the control panel. Is it anywhere in the BIOS?

Comment: 1) I've never seen a computer PSU that was not labeled as to at least the input voltage (not sure it could be legally sold without it in many areas).  2) There is no way for the computer to know what the input voltage is.  3) You may have to physically remove the PSU to view all faces to find the label, but the input voltage is often stamped in the vicinity of the power cord socket.  4) The power cord plug should give you a clue.

Comment: yeah i was trying to avoid unscrewing everything

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the tower case and check if there is a sticker on the side of the power supply? Not very technical, but might get the job done.

Comment: i've tried that, there are no stickers